# Dynamic display of Array data with Image HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Like to ask if I have an array

```
var myArray = [{
    'name': 'Michael',
    'age': '30',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/image1.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Mila',
    'age': '32',
    'sex': 'Female',
    'image': 'upload/image2.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Paul',
    'age': '29',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/image3.jpg'
  }, {
    'name': 'Dennis',
    'age': '25',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/image4.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Tim',
    'age': '27',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/other1.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Erik',
    'age': '24',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/other2.jpg'
  }
];
```

How do I use a `HTML` with `JS` to read the myArray and display in a dynamic `HTML` with clickable link myFunction(name) passing the name in the function call?

[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to make an attempt yourself at least. We can try and help you, if you run into problems with that; but we are not here to give tutorials.

Comment: Have u tried anything? you need to create dynamic html and append the html to a container at run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var myArray = [{
    'name': 'Michael',
    'age': '30',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/image1.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Mila',
    'age': '32',
    'sex': 'Female',
    'image': 'upload/image2.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Paul',
    'age': '29',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/image3.jpg'
  }, {
    'name': 'Dennis',
    'age': '25',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': ' upload / image4.jpg '
  },
  {
    'name': 'Tim',
    'age': '27',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/other1.jpg'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Erik',
    'age': '24',
    'sex': 'Male',
    'image': 'upload/other2.jpg'
  }
];


var htmlString = '';
myArray.forEach((x, i) => {
  htmlString += '<div id="name_' + ++i + '">';
  htmlString += '<div> <img src="dummy.jpg" /> </div> ';
  htmlString += '<div> Name: <span class="name">' + x.name + '</span></div>';
  htmlString += '<div> Age: <span class="age"></span></div>';
  htmlString += '<div> Sex:  <span class="sex"></span></div>';
  htmlString += '<div> <button onClick="getDetails(\'' + x.name + '\')">Get Details </button></div> <br /><br />';
  htmlString += '</div>';
});


document.getElementById('dynamiHtml').innerHTML = htmlString;


function getDetails(name) {
  var index = this.myArray.findIndex(x => x.name === name);
  var obj = this.myArray[index];
  var divId = '#name_' + (index + 1);

  document.querySelector(divId + ' img').src = obj.image;
  document.querySelector(divId + ' .name').innerHTML = obj.name;
  document.querySelector(divId + ' .age').innerHTML = obj.age;
  document.querySelector(divId + ' .sex').innerHTML = obj.sex;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamiHtml">
</div>
```

Comment: @Ronald Tan i have not applied css just given you a js logic.I think you can design by your self and hope my answer is useful to you. Please accept and upvote my answer if it's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Vivek. I realised the example you provided, uses all dummy.jpg? how do I  insert the dynamic image src,

Comment: I thought you want to get details on clicking the button. So i did that way. When you click on get detail button then dynamic image, age and sex will be display. Initially only name will be display with dummy image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example.

```js
var myArray = [
{'name':'Michael', 'age':'30','sex':'Male', 'image':'upload/image1.jpg'},
{'name':'Mila', 'age':'32','sex':'Female','image':'upload/image2.jpg'},
{'name':'Paul', 'age':'29', 'sex':'Male','image':'upload/image3.jpg'},
{'name':'Dennis', 'age':'25','sex':'Male', 'image':'upload/image4.jpg'},
{'name':'Tim', 'age':'27','sex':'Male', 'image':'upload/other1.jpg'},
{'name':'Erik', 'age':'24','sex':'Male', 'image':'upload/other2.jpg'}
]


const html = myArray.map(person => {
  return `
  <section class="person">
    <img src="${person.image}" alt="${person.image}" />
    <ul>
      <li>Name: ${person.name}</li>
      <li>Age: ${person.age}</li>
      <li>Sex: ${person.sex}</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="handleClick('${person.name}')">Click Me</button>
  </section>
  `
}).join('');


document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = html;

function handleClick(e) {
  console.log('you clicked', e)
}
```

```css
:root, html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: darkorange;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.person {
  width: 85%;
  height: 150px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.person img {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #3355dd;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.person ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.person button {
  background: #3355dd;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @RonaldTan, thanks, if you find it useful do you mind upvoting and/or accepting the answer? Good luck with your project.